# Published my first Flutter package- video demo's are not showing up in my read me file

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

Published my first Flutter package, I added video demos and they won't show on pub.dev but they DO show on GitHub.

Any ideas why?

Here is my GitHub [link](https://github.com/SexyBeast007/sequential_navigator)

Package:

https://pub.dev/packages/sequential_navigator

And here is how I have my first few lines of my read me formatted for the media:

```
# Demo

iOS | Android
:-: | :-:
<video src='https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/70868433/142352951-984c9e13-5f48-4611-85fe-010f2c8007e1.mov' width=180/> | <video src='https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/70868433/142352997-b101ed58-7075-440d-9c08-0de657ed623a.mov' width=180/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think they don't allow video playing in pub.dev documentation. You can put gif file.

You can check example of https://pub.dev/packages/video_player

In that [README.md](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/video_player/video_player/README.md)

Raw Data of [README.md](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/plugins/master/packages/video_player/video_player/README.md), Check line no 4.

Thank you

Comment: I will change it to a gif, thank you

Comment: Thanks. If you find its useful, accept the answer :) Appreciated.